# Early return from a script (without a function)

Tags: javascript, performance

I have multiple duplicated external scripts that I want to run just once.

I would like to *return early* on those scripts after the first time doing a small modification to those scripts, something like:

```js
if (window.this_script_have_been_loaded) {
  something_like_return
}

// rest of script

window.this_script_have_been_loaded = true
```

But I do not want to add a big `if` or `function` around the existing code to make it easier to manage. Is there a `return` statement for scripts?

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem - please give more information and show some exiting code in a [mcve] - Are you loading an external JS file? You really have not given enough info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent code from running, place this code inside a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) and exit this block if needed with a [`break` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) and a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

```js
label: {
    console.log('before');
    if (true) break label;
    console.log('after');
}
```